Meaning and usage of the term "elevator word"
I recall coming across the term "elevator words" referring to those which have the effect of raising the level of discussion (complexity, abstractness, analytical rigor). I'd appreciate being pointed toward a definition and/or any similar terms.
Thanks.

Where did you come across this term? There's no such Wikipedia entry, so I don't think it's a well-established term.

Yeah, which is while I'm here. I can recall coming across it just once in an academic / scholarly text of some kind. It may have been something by Dawkins, but on reflection probably someone else, English though, I'm pretty sure. I used it in something of my own then, but can't be bothered to try and dig whatever it was out to check the meaning / usage before I indulge myself again. Naïve me thought it would pop-up through the usual searches, but all I got was dict listings for elevators (sigh). Then this site, on which I pin all my hopes.

It's expected that evidence of research be shown, even if it's just ' "elevator word" is not listed as a compound / strong collocation in Collins, AHD, M-W, ODE or Cambridge Dictionary'. I don't think it's even a weak collocation, just a nonce term used by some academic (and hopefully given an in-document definition) ... and this would be off-topic on ELU.

Yes, just so. I'm asking / looking for some credible source to (a) confirm my recollection and (b) provide for appropriate credit to be given.

I’m voting to close this question because "can't be bothered to try and dig whatever it was out to check the meaning" does not suit here in asking if we ever heard these two words together. Even with the very good answer, it's still not a term in use. So, no.

The only thing involving Richard Dawkins and elevators is rather less elevated.

I've only seen that term used in one work: Ian Hacking's book The Social Construction of What? He claims to have coined the term himself; I'm not sure if other authors have taken it up also. There's a PDF copy of the book (perhaps of dubious legality) here; the relevant excerpt starts with this paragraph on p. 22:

Among the items said by some to be [socially] constructed are facts, truth, reality, and knowledge. In philosophical discussions, these words are often made to work at a different level than words for ideas or words for objects, so I call them elevator words. Facts, truths, reality, and
even knowledge are not objects in the world, like periods of time, little
children, fidgety behavior, or loving-kindness. The words are used to say
something about the world, or about what we say or think about the world. They are at a higher level. Yes, there is a correspondence theory
of truth, according to which true propositions correspond to facts. So are
not facts ‘‘in the world’’? They are not in the world in the same way that
homes, greed, and bailiffs are in the world. Even if we agreed with Wittgenstein that the world is made up of facts and not things, facts would
not be in the world, in the way in which greed and bailiffs are.


Here’s the book... But are you saying you are familiar with this term?

@TinfoilHat I mean, I read that book some time ago, so I'm familiar with the term. I'm not sure anyone who hasn't read that book is.

Bingo! That rings a string of faint bells and is probably what I was loo9king for, although I had imagined something a little more substantial. Many thanks for your sharp memory and the link.

@DerekJ. Quite welcome. The following pages in the book (pp. 23-24) give some more detail and he does come back to the topic a couple times later.

Good. I'll follow through on those pages and browse further. I may well have a hard copy somewhere, but finding it can't compete with the pdf now on my hdd. Thanks for that once more.
